# C#: A two step textbox calculation is only yielding the correct result when clicking my calculate button twice

Tags: c#, button, click

I understand exactly why this is happening, but I can't figure out how to fix it.  Textbox3 is pulling the initial value of textbox2, not the new calculated value.  This is not a school project, rather a simple calculator for my office for some radio hardware we use.  I could fix this by making the button click twice programmatically etc, but I want to know how to fix this the correct way.  My programs are always so simple I get accused of it being "homework" but I can guarantee it is not. I am sure it is simple as a couple paranthesies missing...Thanks in advance

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out origin)
            && double.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out tb2)
             && double.TryParse(textBox4.Text, out channels))

            textBox2.Text = (30.00 - (10 * Math.Log10(origin))).ToString("n2");
            textBox3.Text = (tb2 - (10 * Math.Log10(channels))).ToString("n2");          

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the calculation to:

```
tb2 = 30.00 - (10 * Math.Log10(origin));
var tb3 = tb2 - (10 * Math.Log10(channels));
textBox2.Text = tb2.ToString("n2");
textBox3.Text = tb3.ToString("n2");
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, I just happened to try this one first and it worked!  I appreciate the fast responses!

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning tb2 before you change the value in textbox2.  You should change the code to:

```
            if (double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out origin)
         && double.TryParse(textBox4.Text, out channels))
        {
            textBox2.Text = (30.00 - (10 * Math.Log10(origin))).ToString("n2");
            if (double.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out tb2)
            {
                textBox3.Text = (tb2 - (10 * Math.Log10(channels))).ToString("n2");
            }
        }
```